# Probability of two out of three are same.

Tags: probability

A man throws three fair dice and observes the number on the top face of each. Find the probabilities that:

1. All the three numbers are different?
   $\Large\frac{6\times5\times4}{6^3}$
2. All the three numbers are the same?
   $\Large\frac{6}{6^3}$
3. Prove that the probability that: only two of the three numbers are the same is $\Large\frac{5}{12}$?
   $\Large\frac{18}{6^3}$

Part three is bit confusing as it says only $2$. I suppose that either first throw & second throw, or first throw & third throw, or second throw & third throw

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the answers of i), ii) and iii) should be $1$, since they are the probabilities of three events and only one of them must occur.

More formally:

> If $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are subsets of a probabilistic space $E$ such
>   that:
>
> - $A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_n=E$
> - $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ whenever $i\neq j$
>
> Then $p(A_1)+\cdots+p(A_n)=1$.

Comment: WOW! you are a genius. Is there any exercise questions to this which I can practice?

Comment: Thanks for this tip. But I would accept an answer to which answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take any two dices to be showing same number and the third to be different to give:

$$^3C_2*\frac{6}{6^2}*\frac{5}{6}=\frac{5}{12}$$

Comment: Thanks. Let me summarise if I am getting it correctly. 3C2 is choosing two from three throws. Then 6/6^2 is basically the two throws that needs to be same. And then the last throw which can be any number except the number(from 6/6^2)/

Comment: Exactly You got it right.@Smit